# Github java api

Tags: java, github

I am using org.kohsuke.github java api, and I am trying to create a new subdirectories in an existing Directory in my git repo. Everytime I run my code, I get the same exception:

```
org.kohsuke.github.GHFileNotFoundException:
{"message":"Not Found", 
"documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.13/
v3/git/trees/#create-a-tree"}
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.handleApiError(Requester.java:699)
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:306)
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.to(Requester.java:247)
at org.kohsuke.github.GHTreeBuilder.create(GHTreeBuilder.java:88)
at GitTest.main(GitTest.java:50)
```

This is my code:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
repository = initGithub(okHttpClient);
GHTree test = getTree();
System.out.println(test.getUrl());
System.out.println(test.getSha());
GHTreeBuilder builder = repository.createTree();
try {
     builder.baseTree(test.getSha()).entry("SUB", "040000", "tree", 
     test.getSha(), null).create();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have tested with different params for the.entry() method. Did anybody use this api before? I don't know what I am doing wrong.